# Confused about looping through object to access field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm receiving data from a controller that looks like this when I console.log:

```
{1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}}

1: {datasetID: 1, title: "Adirondack Trout Survey", year: "2015", ADD-startYr: "2015", ADD-endYr: "2015", …}

2: {datasetID: 2, title: "Adirondack Trout Survey", year: "2016", ADD-startYr: "2016", ADD-endYr: "2016", …}

3: {datasetID: 3, title: "Adirondack Trout Survey", year: "2017", ADD-startYr: "2017", ADD-endYr: "2017", …}
```

I'm trying to access the datasetIDs and this was my attempt:

```js
 $(data).each(function(i, d){
     console.log(d.datasetID);
}
```

But I am getting undefined returned.  I'm not sure how to loop through that object and get the dataset IDs?

Thanks!

Comment: start by just logging `d` and see what you're working with- then go from there

Comment: Why is this an object with numeric properties that stores objects? Why is not an array of objects?

Comment: I tried console.log(d) and it gives me back the same as data for some reason...

Comment: I didn't write the controller, so I don't have access to how the data is returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
$.each( data, function(i, d) {
  console.log(d.datasetID);
});
```

Output will be:

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `$(data).each` but what you want is `$.each` ([docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)), with the same callback code.

Comment: I thought the same, but it doesn't: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/9gqaz4pd/. That said, I'd prefer the use of `forEach()` over needlessly including jQuery to loop through a JS structure, but this does work.

Comment: They're different functions for different use-cases. `$.each` is a generic iterator; `$(selector).each` is for iterating over jQuery objects with DOM elements. See the respective docs: https://api.jquery.com/each/ and https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 0):

```
let data = {1: {datasetID: 1, title: "Adirondack Trout Survey"}, 2: {datasetID: 2, title: "Adirondack Trout Survey"}, 3: {datasetID: 3, title: "Adirondack Trout Survey"}}
```

it's an object with indexed props access like this

```
for (const index in data) {
      console.log(data[index].datasetID);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Quick answer: you're using the wrong jQuery "each" method.

Instead of:

```
$(myObject).each(function(i, d) // ...
```

What you want is:

```
$.each(myObject, function(key, val) // ...
```

Complete code:

```
$.each(data, function(key, val){
  console.log(val.datasetID); // val, in this case, is your nested object
});
```

See the differences from the docs:

- https://api.jquery.com/each/
- https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

#### Vanilla version

You can also do this without jQuery, by using the `Object.keys` method like so:

```
Object.keys(myObject).forEach(function(key) {
  var val = myObject[key];

  // ... do the things ...

});
```

Just make sure you have browser support for it.

Cheers!

Comment: You could also use `Object.values()`, then you don't need `var val = myObject[key]`